# EEVEE - PNG image with transparency causing background to show through

Tags: eevee-render-engine

EEVEE - How to fix a PNG image with transparency from bleeding through?

1. the alpha must cast shadows (alpha hashed, alpha clip)
2. random parts of the opaque image is acting as if it's transparent (the background is bleeding through) CYCLES does not appear to have this issue.
   [image: EEVEEAlphaBleed]

[image: AlphaShader]

[image: CYCLES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend mode is Clip - that means that pixels with transparency below defined level becomes transparent completely. Try to use different blend mode, or adjust clip threshold.

Comment: I agree, and used all of the available settings and still had the issue, so it must be "Clip Threshhold" needs adjustment ~ thanks